# Using ouput parameter of type SYS_refcursor

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, oracle10g, out-parameters, sys-refcursor

In my database I have a stored procedure with an OUTPUT parameter of type SYS_REFCURSOR. The application side is wrtitten in C#. Can I assign this procedure's output parameter to  a Datatable like:

```
 .............
 OracleConnection con=new OracleConnection(......);
 OracleCommand cmd=new OracleCommand("MyStoredProc",con);
 cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("REC_CUR",OracleType.Cursor).Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
 con.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 DataTable dt=(DataTable)cmd.Parameters["REC_CUR"].value;//is this legal?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer to my own question. If the output parametr of a stored procedure is of type SYS_REFCURSOR then the command

```
cmd.Parameters["REC_CUR"].value
```

will return an OracleDataReader object, not a table. And there's no implicit , nor explicit cast from OracledataReader to DataTable.

Comment: It should be mentioned there's no implicit cast from any DataReader to DataTable (not just OracleDataReader). The `DataTable.Load (IDataReader)` Method can be used instead. e.g.  `DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.Load((OracleDataReader)cmd.Parameters["REF_CUR"].value);`

Comment: Make sure you don't close your connection object until after you have finished reading the data or loading it into a DataTable.  No exception is thrown if your DataReader is closed when you call DataTable.Load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OracleDataAdapter` like below,

sample code with multiple out parameters with `RefCursor` :

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SP1", OraCon) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure })
{
    var parm_nic = cmd.Parameters.Add("parm_nic", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
    parm_nic.Value = msgBody;

    var pram_Name = cmd.Parameters.Add("pram_Name", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 150, ParameterDirection.Output);
    var pram_PAdress = cmd.Parameters.Add("pram_PAdress", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 150, ParameterDirection.Output);
    var output = cmd.Parameters.Add("pram_status", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
    OraCon.Open();

    OracleDataAdapter ad = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    OracleCommandBuilder cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(ad);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ad.Fill(dt);

    var address = pram_PAdress.Value;
    var name = pram_Name.Value;
}
```