# Getting Oracle Data from a stored procedure from a "C#" web app

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm having a hard time getting my c# code to run a stored procedure and return back the rows so I can display on my datagrid.  I have searched the site and found others with the same issue but I tried the fixes suggested and an still getting a "wrong number or types of arguments in call" error.

This is my stored procedure code

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE GetData
(
  P_RECS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  P_YEARLIST IN VARCHAR2
)
AS 
BEGIN  
 OPEN P_RECS FOR 
  select desc
  from emp_data
  where trim(SYear) in (P_YEARLIST)
  order by upper(trim(SYear)) asc ;
END GetData ;
```

This is my C# code

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("GetData", conn))
{
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  OracleParameter opRefCur = new OracleParameter();
  opRefCur.ParameterName = "P_RECS";
  opRefCur.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;      
  opRefCur.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

  OracleParameter opYearList = new OracleParameter();
  opYearList.ParameterName = "P_YEARLIST";
  opYearList.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
  opYearList.Value = '1973';
  opYearList.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

  cmd.Parameters.Add(opRefCur);
  cmd.Parameters.Add(opYearList);

  try
  {
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

  }
}
```

This is just the beginning of this stored procedure.  I have to add many more parameters.  I'm sure it is something simple and I have looked over the code multiple times but I'm unable to correct it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't you change the `Direction` of `opRefCur` to `ParameterDirection.Output`? And perhaps the type should be changed to `Cursor` instead of `RefCursor`? Check this thread: [Getting Cursor from Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738787/using-ouput-parameter-of-type-sys-refcursor)

Comment: Hi Przemyslaw, I changed the direction to output for the refcur, that stopped the error but i'm still not seeing data returned.  If I run this procedure in sql plus it returns back the rows i'm expecting but through my c# app it is not.  What OracleDbType should I use if I'm using cursor not refcursor?  Thank you

Comment: Can you try what was proposed by Conrad Frix in the thread that I provided link to? This: `DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.Load((OracleDataReader)cmd.Parameters["REF_CUR"].value);`

Comment: Przemyslaw,  I tried this code DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Load((OracleDataReader)cmd.Parameters["P_RECS"].Value); and it still errors on the dt.Load row. I get {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: dataReader"}